# Change data frame values based on the values of other elements in the same row in r

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I want to change the value of an element in a data frame row based on whether other elements in the same row are a certain value.

I have a data frame of the following form:

```
    p_id year         Id   number1    number2          result 
   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>           <dbl> 
 1     1 1968          1         1          0              NA      
 2     1 1969          1         1         10              NA  
 3     1 1970         81         9          7              NA  
 4     1 1971          0         0          0              NA    
 5     1 1972          0         0         10              NA 
 6     1 1973          0         0          0              NA  
 7     1 1974          1         1         10              NA
```

When Id = 1, number1 = 1 and number2 = 10 i want to write a 1 into the result column, otherwise a 0.

So this is what it should look like:

```
    p_id year         Id   number1    number2          result 
   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>           <dbl> 
 1     1 1968          1         1          0               0      
 2     1 1969          1         1         10               1
 3     1 1970         81         9          7               0  
 4     1 1971          0         0          0               0    
 5     1 1972          0         0         10               0 
 6     1 1973          0         0          0               0
 7     1 1974          1         1         10               1
```

There should be a way to solve this with, i guess, lapply().

Im sorry if this is a repost, i could not find a solution so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another option without `ifelse`

```
data$result <- with(data, +(Id == 1 & number1 == 1& number2 == 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data frame you are trying to alter is called `data` the below line of code should achieve your desired result.

```
data$result < -ifelse(data$Id = 1 & data$number1 = 1 & data$number2 = 10, 1, 0)
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Assume your `data.frame` is called `d1`:

```
d1[["result"]] <-  ifelse(d1[["Id"]] == 1L & d1[["numer1"]] == 1L & d1[["number2"]] == 10L, 1L, 0L)
```